# how to read file with pandas correctly

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, text

I try to read txt file like this:

```
id  sub_id  identity    q_length    alignment_length    mismatches  gap_opens   evalue  bit_score   stitle
>ID1757 49.512  454 410 207 0   3.71e-159   461 Sequence 11511 from patent US 8343764         
>ID6556 gb|AEI19864.1|  56.442  372 326 140 1   1.36e-135   394 Sequence 412 from patent US 7960148
```

I need to set columns correctly. But in the last column I have several words. I need to put it in one column.

I also have this case:

```
id  sub_id  identity    q_length    alignment_length    mismatches  gap_opens   evalue  bit_score stitle
>ID54545    sp|Q59226.1|    31.340  454 418 255 11  8.73e-49    178 RecName: Full=Cyclomaltodextrinase; Short=CDase; Short=CDase I-5; AltName: Full=Cyclomaltodextrin hydrolase, decycling [Bacillus sp. (in: firmicutes)]
```

And I need to put All text after RecName to one column

I tried to set column names and print last column to see how system defines columns.

```
df1_column_names = ['id'    'sub_id'    'identity'  'q_length'  'alignment_length'  'mismatches'    
'gap_opens' 'evalue'    'bit_score' 'stitle']
df1 = pd.read_csv('path', names=df1_column_names)

newdf = df1['stitle']

newdf.to_csv('path', index=False)
```

But I got an error. And also in other cases the system define the last column not as 'Sequence 412 from patent US 7960148' for example but '7960148'

Comment: Aren't you missing `sub_id` in the first row with `ID1757` ?

Comment: "But I got an error", what error did you get?

Comment: I don't think pandas will read this successfully. But you could write some regular expressions that parses line by line and then write a true CSV file - either to disk or to to io.StringIO. Then you have something pandas can use.